# DataFrames getting distorted while unpacking list of dataframes in Python Streamlit, with each dataframe looking different from the other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, streamlit

I am working on Streamlit in python.

I have created a function which allows the user to upload multiple files, reads those files one by one and stores them to a dataframe. I want this function to return all those dataframes to a separate .py file, for which I appended all the dataframes to a list i.e. list of dataframes, and here my problem started!

The list named 'all_df_list' has all the dataframes in it.
But when I unpack this list in the other python script and see the dataframes on that other script, the result is getting distorted i.e. Dataframes are not able to hold the shape and looks which it used to be, before appending it to the list.

Here is the code snippet:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def user_selection(action):

    operation_mode = action
    mydf = pd.DataFrame()

    with st.sidebar:
         if operation_mode == 'Multiple_files':
            uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose required files", accept_multiple_files = True)
            all_df_list = []
            for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                mydf = mydf.iloc[0:0]
                if uploaded_file.name is not None:
                   # For now, assuming the user will only upload multiple csv files
                   mydf = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file) 
                   all_df_list.append(mydf)
            st.write(all_df_list)
            return all_df_list
```

Now, lets say, I called this function in another script and unpacked the list 'all_df_list' as:

```py
*all_dfs = user_selection('Multiple_files')
st.write(all_dfs[0]) # the dataframe all_dfs[0] has lost its shape and original orientation.
```

How can I successfully return multiple dataframes via function, such that when I unpack them I should be able to see the dataframes as they were before appending them to the list.

Any lead on this will help. Thank you.

Comment: what do you intend to do with mydf = mydf.iloc[0:0]? I seem to see multiple irrelevant lines of code and inappropriate code construction. is your main goal only to return list of dfs?

Answer (score 0):

Just like I wrote in the comment section, I seem to see irrelevant lines of code and inappropriate code construction rather than undesired format of dataframes returned by `user_selection`:

If you are only looking to return list of dfs:

```py
def user_selection(action):

    operation_mode = action
    mydf = pd.DataFrame()
    all_df_list = []
    with st.sidebar:
        if operation_mode == 'Multiple_files':
            uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose required files", accept_multiple_files=True)
            if uploaded_files:
                for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                    mydf = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
                    all_df_list.append(mydf)
                st.write(all_df_list)
    return all_df_list
```

Call this function in another script:

```py
all_dfs = user_selection('Multiple_files')
if all_dfs:
    st.write(all_dfs[0])
```